# WordPress reports wrong version of php

Tags: php, centos-6, wordpress

I have a centos 6 Linux server with a whm and cpanel installed. I've recently updated the PHP version to 7 through the whm and applied it to the website on the server in both whm and cpanel in the multi-PHP version screen.

This all looks okay in the cpanel and when I check PHP version in ssh it says 7.2. But when I go back to WordPress it still says its running PHP 5.6 and showing the PHP update required message in the WordPress dashboard.

When I delete the PHP 5.6 version from the whm the website goes down so it has to be connected to the whm somehow.  How do I point the website to use php7.2?

Comment: Have you restarted your webserver since upgrading?

Comment: I've restarted nginx.

Comment: Ok, so you probably run PHP-FPM. Try restarting this, or restart the entire server. It'll be because your PHP config will still have old because the service is running, restart and the new config will read

Comment: I gracefully rebooted the server and it is now working. Good job you suggested it also, I had already done it but I think the ajax on the cpanel timed out so it looks like it's still rebooting. Crisis Averted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting Nginx alone will not reload the PHP config as the service still has old config data in memory, hence your site not showing accurate data.

You can either reload PHP-FPM or restart your server to allow the new config data to be read by PHP.